# Is there any evidence that subatomic particles are affected by gravity?

Tags: gravity, subatomic

If so what experiment has been done to show this?

Comment: Affected how? After all, I'm made up of subatomic particles, and I'm clearly affected by gravity.

Comment: The Milliken oil drop experiment.

Comment: Gravity is the curvature of spacetime due to matter and energy. Subatomic particles exist in spacetime, therefore they must be affected by gravity. I suppose the evidence is that gravity, by its very nature, affects everything in the universe

Comment: It's a stretch, but I think a fairly widespread impression that subatomic particles might not be affected by gravity stems from its role as the Heisenberg conjugate of time, together with the fact that memory functions through the use of electrons:  These two considerations may've been combined into the notion (popularized by Feynman) that antiparticles are particles traveling backward in time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. For the phrasing of this question, the neutron qualifies.

Neutrons have been slowed and collected, which are diverted from nuclear reactors via beamports. The methods for doing this are quite complicated, but in the final state, they are confined within a box where the "walls" present a nuclear barrier to the neutrons. The neutrons have a wavelength longer than the spacing between atoms in the wall, thus, they bounce off. An interesting fact about the design is that the containment area doesn't need a "top" because the neutrons are at such a low energy that thermal movement isn't enough for them to leap out. This phenomenon, alone, is a physical demonstration of gravitational affects on subatomic particles.

So thorough is our understanding and testing of these particles in gravity, that [quantized levels of height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultracold_neutrons#Observation_of_the_gravitational_interactions_of_the_neutron) have been observed for ultra-cold neutrons.