# How do we know that electrons are affected by gravity?

Tags: forces, gravity, electrons, neutrons

There are some theories of gravity which explain it as emerging from other fundamental forces. To better understand the evidence for and against these theories, I would like to have a better understanding of evidence for the mainstream assumption that gravity affects all particles to a degree which is proportional to their mass.

Obviously, most of our observations of gravity measure its influence in attractions between large objects consisting of atoms.

Now, in [an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162313/is-there-any-evidence-that-subatomic-particles-are-affected-by-gravity/162317#162317) to the question of whether subatomic particles are affected by gravity, Alan Rominger describes experiments which appear to have isolated the influence of gravitaty on ultracold neutrons. That is very interesting.

But assuming these results are correct, it seems consistent with current evidence that gravity might be a weak attraction between hadrons (protons and neutrons), not affecting other particles.

Do we, for example, have direct evidence that gravity affects electrons? (Please don't say "the Millikan oil drop experiment"!)

Comment: Surely the percentage of electrons differs enough between carbon and gold that feathers would fall measurably slower in a vacuum if gravity didn't attract electrons.

Comment: http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.168.737

Comment: In fact, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle#Tests_of_the_weak_equivalence_principle) says this experiment was done using aluminum and platinum, which is clearly a big enough difference to account for electrons..

Comment: @PeterShor: I'm not so sure about that. By my (admittedly quick) calculation  1 kg of Be-9 contains 0.00024 kg of electrons. 1 kg of U-238: 0.00021 kg of electrons. The difference is small.

Comment: @Gert: Yes, but the experiment was sensitive to one part in 10^(-12). So while the difference is small, it's large enough to have been detected by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: @PeterShor: actually, I'm not sure which experiment you're referring to. Link? Ta.

Comment: Braginski and Panov. The [Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle#Tests_of_the_weak_equivalence_principle) says they tested aluminum and platinum (which give electron concentrations comparable to Be and U), and the experiment was accurate to one part in 10^12. This accuracy has apparently been disputed by other experimenters, but you only need one part in 10^5 to show electrons are affected by gravity.

Comment: The Dessler et al reference from @CountIblis, "Gravitationally Induced Electric Fields in Conductors", makes predictions about the gravitationally-induced electric field which are based on the atomic gravitational mass, not the electron gravitational mass - the dominant effect is compression of the metal lattice by gravity. Otherwise I'd say it's a very good idea.

Comment: @PeterShor: The torsion-balance experiments of Braginski and Panov, or those of Roll et al (which I found in English), or originally Eotvos, are promising but I think the results are diminished by the fact that we haven't isolated individual electrons. All we know from these experiments is that a neutron has the same ratio of gravitational to inertial mass as a (proton, electron) pair. But beta decay tells us perhaps that we can see a neutron as a proton and electron bound up together, so this was not so surprising.

Comment: As I understand it, there is a certain component of the mass of various composite particles like hadrons, or atomic nuclei, which is due to binding energy. If this mass contribution differs in aluminum and gold by more than 10^-12 of the total, then I would say that the torsion-balance experiments provide a good test of the equivalence principle, because they show that this somewhat arbitrary mass is treated the same by gravity and inertia. I guess that is a bit off-topic, though, because my question was about electrons.

Comment: You've changed your question, then, because you started by asking whether it was possible that gravity affected hadrons but not electrons.

Comment: @PeterShor: I still appreciate your answers, but in light of them the question seems somewhat ill-posed. For example, what does it mean to talk about gravity affecting hadrons or gravity affecting electrons, when a measurable fraction (more than 10^-9 by my estimation) of the mass of an atom is actually due to the electrical binding energy between protons and orbital electrons? Anyway, thank you for contributing references to those experiments. My opinions have changed and improved which is good.